# Finding a Fourier series for a function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

> Find the Fourier series for 
>   $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
> x + 1, \ \ &-1\leq x < 0\\
> 1 - x \ \ &0\leq x < 1
> \end{cases}$$

I know that the full Fourier series of $\phi(x)$ on $- l < x < l$ is defines as 
$$\phi(x) = \frac{1}{2}A_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\cos\frac{n\pi x}{l} + B_n \sin\frac{n\pi x}{l}$$
But I am not sure how to apply this to $f(x)$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, the whole problem is to find the coefficients $A_n,B_n$. They are given by a formula in terms of $f(x).$

Comment: with the change of variable $y=\pi x$ you can apply the classical Fourier series to $g(y)=f(y/\pi)=f(x)$

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/FourierSeries.aspx

Comment: @Lovsovs What would $L$ be in this case for $A_0$?

Comment: Since the function is ___even___ one can use just cosine Fourier series instead of the full trig one.

Comment: derivate twice, apply Diracs delta and use the fourier complex series, done.